# Node Js ES6 request

Tags: nodejs, es6

Tengo el siguiente código en python

```
rc = requests.get(url).json()
auth_url = rc['authURL']
pin_url = rc['pinURL'] 
client_id = rc['clientid']
```

Cómo puedo pasar este mismo código a `NodeJS` en `ES6` he intentado usar el modulo [request](https://github.com/request/request) y el de [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) pero estos trabajan con promesas y no he podido asignar el valor que retorna el **request** ya que termina la ejecución antes de que obtenga la promesa es que soy nuevo en `NodeJS`.

He intentado algo así

```
class urls {

    getRc (){
        return Axios.get(urlconfig)
    }

    async getAuthUrl(){
        this.getRc().then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
    }

}

module.exports = urls
```